# SQL Server: Time Series Table Design

Tags: sql-server, database-design, temporal-tables

I am creating a time series database that follows the table structure here: [Storing intervals of time with no overlaps.](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/03/08/storing-intervals-of-time-with-no-overlaps.aspx)  The difference with my design is that the `FinishedAt` column changes every time a user updates that particular record (you can actually see my question on his site at the bottom).

Basically, I have a `FinishedAt` column that has the current record with a date of `9999-12-31` until the next record with the same business key gets updated (in his example that key would be the `SettingID`). I run into the problem with his `FK_IntegerSettings_SettingID_PreviousFinishedAt` since I cannot make `FinishedAt` part of my primary key. I cannot make it part of my primary key because it is always changing....**but** is it okay to make `FinishedAt` part of **my** primary key, which would involve updating the primary key? Is this frowned upon even in a time series table?

I realize I can still use his other constraints, but I loose the very important `foreign key` constraint. This is my first encounter with this type of design so any direction will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately your link is hidden behind a log-in wall :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A foreign key can reference a unique constraint, not necessarily only a primary key, so if you want to be a purist, include `FinishedAt` (and whatever else you need) in the parent table's unique constraint and use that to define the foreign key.

Comment: I did not know you could do that (you learn something new every day, Thanks!) @mustaccio

Comment: Just want to add that a foreign key can reference a unique index too, not just a primary key or unique constraint.  Personally, I prefer unique constraints rather than unique indexes when the purpose is data integrity rather than just performance.